# Cosa significa "rameggiare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> Varga fece una tirata sul cinismo dell'imputato, finì proclamando: "E dunque, anche ammettendo che la signora avesse avuto la capacità di concepire e di attuare un così diabolico disegno (e perché poi, se nemmeno il marito riusciva a indicare un interesse, un movente?), è pensabile fosse arrivata a sacrificare l'innocente bestiola cui, per ammissione di colui che vorrebbe rovesciare su di lei l'accusa che lo stringe, era tanto affezionata?". Per l'aula **rameggiò** un sussurro di indignazione, di incredulità; la presidentessa della Protezione Animali, presente a tutte le udienze nella qualità e in quanto amica della signora, gridò: "Impossibile!" e l'avvocato fece verso il farmacista un segno che voleva dire irrimediabilmente persa la causa.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "rameggiò un sussurro" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il verbo "rameggiare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato di [rameggiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rameggiare/) adatto al contesto da te citato è il seguente:

> 2. intr. (aus. avere), letter. Ramificarsi, distendere i rami, detto delle piante e, fig., delle corna del cervo e sim.: *Ride sepolta a
>    l’imo una foresta Breve, e rameggia immobile* (Carducci).

Qui viene inteso in senso figurato come ramificarsi, diramarsi, diffondersi per l'aula.

Comment: si potrebbe usare anche (più comunemente) "serpeggiare" anche se il significato è leggermente diverso, e il verbo qui usato indica il fatto che il "sussulto di indignazione" si è come moltiplicato passando di bocca in bocca, diramandosi in tutte le direzioni.